# Selenium WebDriver on Python. How to use variable created during test in the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I wanna alert variable `(a = "Text" for example)` which I assigned during test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
from selenium import webdriver                  

browser = webdriver.Firefox()                
a = "hello"
browser.execute_script("alert('"+a+"');")
```

If a is integer use str(a) instead of "a"

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works!! Only you skipped one single quote)

Comment: @KirillZhukov my pleasure, hope your problem is solved.